# Reference .Net lib in a .Net Core project

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, itext

I currently have a ASP.Net Core app, which implies that all my class libraries are .Net core class libraries.

In one of those libraries, I need to use `iTextSharp`, which does not support .Net Core.
I don't really care to execute this on linux, I just like the modularity of Asp.Net Core and all the template with the modern web development.

I found this: [Unable to use iTextSharp with ASP.NET 5 Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29717625/unable-to-use-itextsharp-with-asp-net-5-core) which seems to indicate that we can reference the .Net 4.6 in a .Net core app.

But since VS2017, there is no more `project.json`, since it's directly included in the `*.csproj`.

So:

1. Is it possible to reference a .Net 4.6(well a library from .Net full framework) in a .Net core library(if we are not gonna use it somewhere else than IIS?

   2. If yes, how?
   3. If no, do you have any idea what I can do?

Comment: BTW, have you checked "unofficial" iTextSharp builds that can be referenced from .NET Core apps, like https://www.nuget.org/packages/iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core/ ?

Comment: @VitaliyFedorchenko I wanted to test your approach(for some other needs(tests), it would help if its true .net core), so I created a .NetCore project, imported the package you indicated. I can create the PdfReader, but I can't find the `SimpleTextExtractionStrategy` class in it?

Comment: I guess SimpleTextExtractionStrategy doesn't exist in iTextSharp 4.1.6 ( https://github.com/schourode/iTextSharp-LGPL ) and was added later. All versions after 4.1.6 are non LGPL and require commercial license. If you're commercial iTextSharp user you contact their representatives and ask for .NET Core support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the article [Use ASP.NET Core 1.1 with .NET 4.6](https://jonhilton.net/2017/03/14/use-asp-net-core-1-1-with-net-4-without-visual-studio/).

You simply need to edit your `*.csproj` file and replace `netcoreapp1.1` to `net46`. When you do that your .NET Core app will run on full framework and you will be able to install `iTextSharp` package.

**EDIT:**
To resolve issue with webpack middleware you need to directly reference `System.Net.Http 4.3.1` package as mentioned in [this comment](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/487#issuecomment-282143521).

Comment: I was just reading it, I tried, now it compile but I get some exception `Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies.  HRESULT : 0x80131040, any idea?

Comment: It's on `app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware`of the `Startup.cs`

Comment: I tried to add the corresponding nugget package, but still got this error.

Not sure why, I got more info on this HRESULT: `The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.`

Comment: That could be because previously package was referenced for .net core app. Try to remove package and install again.

Comment: @J4N, I have just tried on fresh mvc project, encountered similar issue https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/5528, solved that by removing browser link and all worked. Maybe webpack has some specific requirements.

Comment: What do you need by "Some specific requirement" Why does it build if the requirement are not met?

Comment: It is runtime requirement for assembly version. What is the package? I could try it on my laptop. Otherwise you could create another question or post an issue on github.

Comment: It's easy to reproduce: create a new angular2 project: `dotnet new angular`, edit the csproj, open it in VS2017, debug it.

Comment: Try directly reference System.Net.Http 4.3.1 package as mentioned in this comment https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/487#issuecomment-282143521

Comment: Yes! It is working!!!!!! So weird, it makes 8h that I'm trying to have this working!

You should add this in your answer and I accept it!

Comment: I am happy that it helped :). You original question was not about this issue, but sure, I can update my answer.